# Setting java home directory Jboss-as-7.1.1

Tags: java, jboss

I am trying to set my `JAVA_HOME` to the directory of my local JDK but I am confuse where to set in. Is it in environment variable in windows or in `standalone.conf.bat` file? Can anyone show me steps to set the directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this JDK is sufficient for all the project you run on your local machine, you can set the `JAVA_HOME` variable as Windows environment variable.

For this right clic on **Computeur > Properties > Advanced system settings**; go to the **Advanced** tab and in the bottom you will have a **Environment Variables** button. Clic on it, and here you can manage environment variable. Add a **System variable**, with `JAVA_HOME` as key, and the jdk directory as value (`C:\...`)